Convert texts in pdf pages into table in R
There are some PDF pages that I would like to convert into tables in R. An example of the data is shown in the picture: 
To get an idea from the picture, this is the Index from the book I am using. You will see that the both genus and family species names are capitalized the first letter, and their corresponding epithet and var are indented and in lower cases. Page number is after the ,.
Since the format here is a bit confusing, I would like to explain my desired outputs in detail. I think 4 columns would be ideal (Column names: genus/Family, epithet, underspp, no).

If we see a full species name i.e., Acacia koa, 259. I would like to put Acacia in the first column, koa in the second column, and the number will be in the fourth column.
If we see one genus name and their orresponding epithet indented names, the idea would be the same as the first case.
If we see the epithet have their corresponding var indented names, the var part will be in the third column. The rest would be like other cases.

This is the example I want to have:



genus/Family
epithet
underspp
no




Acacia
koa

259


Aconiopteris
gorgoneum

154


Aconiopteris
obtusa

154


Acrostichum
aemulum

154


Adenophorus
pinnatifidus

38, 39-41,40,42


Adenophorus
pinnatifidus
var. rockii
40,41


....
....
....
....



I was looking around and found the R package pdftools. Any suggestions in this case? I hope my explanation is clear.

You posted an image to show what is in your PDF.  Is your PDF actually an image or does it have selectable text?  You gave your post the pdftools tag.  Did you try to use pdf_text or pdf_ocr_text  on the pages?

@G5W I clipped one page of my pdf and posted it here. And yes, it does. All the contents in this picture are selectable. I did use but it gave me not what I expect. I will edit the question now
